# Elixir OptionParser accepts ["--form", "blah"]

Tags: elixir

I am new to learning Elixir.

As a starting point, I wanted to implement small commandline applications. I stumbled upon the following in iex:

```
args = ["--form", "blah"]
OptionParser.parse(args, switches: [src: :string])
```

I would've expected a result of `{[],[],[form: "blah"]}`.

Instead I' receive `{[form: "blah"],[],[]}`

Am I overlooking something?

Additionally:

If I assign args `args=["--folm", "lolo"]` the result is `{[], [], [{"--folm", "lolo"}]}` what I expect.

I thought `switches:` defines *valid switches*. And as long, as I didn't define `form: :string`, I would not expect it to be accepted. There seems to be something special with `form`, I do not get at the moment.

Comment: Why did you expect that result? The last element is the errors list and there is no error here..?

Comment: @Dogbert I updated my question. I thought, OptionParser accepts only switches I define _explicitely_, and "form", doesn't fit into that.

Comment: Wow, that was an interesting (or frustrating?) thing to debug! I think I've found the reason (posted an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought `switches:` defines *valid switches*. And as long, as I didn't define `form: :string`, I would not expect it to be accepted. There seems to be something special with `form`, I do not get at the moment.

In the "dynamic" mode, switches with names that exist as atoms in the current Erlang VM are parsed into the valid list, while those that don't exist are put in the error list. This can be verified like this:

```
iex(1)> OptionParser.parse(["--form", "blah"], switches: [src: :string])
{[form: "blah"], [], []}
iex(2)> OptionParser.parse(["--folm", "blah"], switches: [src: :string])
{[], [], [{"--folm", "blah"}]}
iex(3)> :folm # Create this atom
:folm
iex(4)> OptionParser.parse(["--folm", "blah"], switches: [src: :string])
{[folm: "blah"], [], []}
```

`--form` parses in the first attempt because Elixir creates that atom somewhere while starting:

```
$ erl -noshell -eval 'io:format("~p", [binary_to_existing_atom(<<"form">>, utf8)]), init:stop().'
form
```

This is documented in the section "Parsing dynamic switches" of [`OptionParser.parse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/OptionParser.html#parse/2):

> In other words, when using dynamic mode, Elixir will do the correct thing and only parse options that are used by the runtime, ignoring all others. If you would like to parse all switches, regardless if they exist or not, you can force creation of atoms by passing allow_nonexistent_atoms: true as option. Such option is useful when you are building command-line applications that receive dynamically-named arguments but must be used with care on long-running systems.

This behavior can be turned off by using using the strict switches mode:

```
iex(5)> OptionParser.parse(["--form", "blah"], strict: [src: :string])
{[], ["blah"], [{"--form", nil}]}
iex(6)> OptionParser.parse(["--folm", "blah"], strict: [src: :string])
{[], ["blah"], [{"--folm", nil}]}
iex(7)> OptionParser.parse(["--form", "blah", "--src", "blah2"], strict: [src: :string])
{[src: "blah2"], ["blah"], [{"--form", nil}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I should've read the documentation earlier, as it tells right away: »:switches - defines some switches and their types. This function still attempts to parse switches that are not in this list.« :D https://elixirschool.com/lessons/advanced/escripts/ e.g. should make it clear, that `strict:` is, what you typically want.